# Typescript -> ES5 issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I write this in typescript:

```
const mask = [...Array(10)].map((item) => 0);
```

In the node console it produces a array of 10 zeros:

```
> [...Array(10)].map((item) => 0);
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Once transpilied in javascript, it produces:

```
var mask = Array(10).slice().map(function (item) { return 0; });
```

But this is not equivalent:

```
> Array(10).slice().map(function (item) { return 0; })
[ , , , , , , , , ,  ]
```

I was under the impression that typescript is supposed to produced iso-functional code. Was I wrong? Should I pay attention to everything TS is producing?

I am using node v7, tsc 1.20150623.0 with this config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "outDir": ".tmp/js",
    "rootDir": "js"
  }
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce this, **but**: your TS, copy and pasted, works fine. The `map` in the JS form is failing, but it shouldn't be. Something funny is going on.

Comment: @ssube: The JS is behaving as expected. The `.slice()` method ignores holes in the Array, so it's an accurate representation of the original. See [22.1.3.22 Array.prototype.slice (start, end)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.slice), specifically point 15 (d), where *kPresent* is the result of *HasProperty* of the current index.

Comment: @squint not exactly, `slice` _does_ give you the same array that has 10 empty indeces. However, `.map` will ignore them as the "functional" family of methods - `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, `some`, etc. only go over values of the array that are present.

Comment: @vlaz: Right, both slice and map are ignoring them, so the result is still an Array with empty slots. Unless I've misunderstood where the perceived issue is? This is a Typescript bug AFAICT.

Comment: @squint sorry, I thought you meant that `Array(10).slice()` will produce a new completely empty array. I see I was reading that wrong, you're correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known and open issue with TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856) that should be fixed in TypeScript 2.1.

> The following code:
>
> ```
> [...(new Array(5))]
> ```
>
> translates into:
>
> ```
> (new Array(5)).slice();
> ```
>
> However, the ES6 meaning is not the same. See the output below:
>
> ```
> > [...(new Array(5))]
> [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
> > (new Array(5)).slice();
> [ , , , ,  ]
> ```
>
> Expected behavior:
>
> ```
> Array.apply(null, Array(5))
> ```